# How to achieve Synchronous behaviour while extracting from Resque Queue?

Tags: node.js, redis, resque

I have a case, where I enqueue some messages using 'queue'. Now I want to extract these messages serially. I am using 'worker' but it fires all messages in async way calling my callbackfunction for each message at the same time. Is there a way I can control the worker to extract only a single message or call some de-queue message serially?

```
// Code enqueuing 3 messages...
var queue = new NR.queue({connection: connectionDetails});

queue.enqueue(config.Redis.resquequeuename, config.Redis.resquequeuejob, {
message_id: 1,
message_payload: "this is a test body of my message"
});
queue.enqueue(config.Redis.resquequeuename, config.Redis.resquequeuejob, {
message_id: 2,
message_payload: "this is a test body of my message"
});
queue.enqueue(config.Redis.resquequeuename, config.Redis.resquequeuejob, {
message_id: 3,
message_payload: "this is a test body of my message"
});

// Code using worker to dequeue messages
var GetQueueMessage = function(appcallback){

var job = {};
job[config.Redis.resquequeuejob] = {
plugins: [],
pluginOptions: {},
perform: function(compositemessage, callback){
callback(null, appcallback(null, compositemessage));
}
};

var workername = os.hostname() + ":" + process.pid;
var worker = new NR.worker({connection: connectionDetails, queues: [config.Redis.resquequeuename], 'name': workername}, job);
worker.connect(function(){
worker.workerCleanup();

console.log("Worker starting, Resque worker. Worker name: "+ workername);

worker.start();
});
// different even handlers for worker here...
};

workerGetQueueMessage(function(err, pCompositeMessage){
console.log("Composite Message returned from Worker: " + JSON.stringify(pCompositeMessage));
console.log(new Date(dt.now()));
});
```

Comment: if you do not need parallel processing then why are you using queue ?

Comment: Queuing doesn't necessarily dictate parallel processing. I want to hold all received messages in a queue, then process them serially (one-by-one)

Comment: I meant to say why are you using node resque. It will create multiple worker and they will process your messages parallely.